# Symfony router annotations override default controller prefix

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a little question about @Routing annotations in symfony.

I have a controller in which i add a default @Route('/api/v1/users'), and in this controller I have a method with @Route('/{userId}/documents'}).

Since I have V2 that add a parameters int this route, but the main logic on method stay the same, I wanted to add a new route ( for V2) on the same method @Route(/api/v2/users/{userId}/{newParam}/documents').

But like there is a default @Route on the controller the route I generate are not good ( because they use the v1 prefix :

Generated :
/api/v1/users/{userId]/documents
/api/v1/users/api/v2/users/{userId]/{newParam}/documents

And I want to have this :
/api/v1/users/{userId]/documents
/api/v2/users/{userId]/{newParam}/documents

Does it exist a way to achieve that without a new controller ? Maybe some options I do not find on @Route ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do it with annotation.
The only solution i found is to add your v2 route in routes.yml and match it with the same controller function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).